# Shortest path to inspect a polyhedron

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, geodesics

This is a variant of two as-yet unsolved MO questions cited below.
Let $P$ be a closed polyhedron in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
The task is to find a shortest path $\sigma$ on the surface of $P$ from which
all the surface may be "inspected," which is interpreted as requiring
that $\sigma$ touch every face of $P$. The path $\sigma$ might only touch a
corner or edge of a face, but that suffices to inspect the face.
For example, these seem straightforward:

---

[image: Inspect123]

          

<sup>Optimal inspection paths on the tetrahedron, cube, octahedron.</sup>

---

I am less certain of the icosahedron.
**Update**: Gerhard Paseman's $5$-edge path is shorter.

---

[image: InspectIcosa]

          

<sup>Left path length: $2+\sqrt{13} \approx 5.6$. Right: $5$.</sup>

---

I believe it is not difficult to show the problem is NP-hard (by reduction from TSP), so approximations are likely necessary.
I have a sense, perhaps a vague memory, that this has been investigated in the
literature, maybe only for restricted sets of convex polyhedra
(e.g., the Platonic & Archimedean solids).
But I have not been able to find any citations.
If anyone can find a reference, or make a useful observation, it would be appreciated.

---

["Optimal inspection path on a sphere"](https://mathoverflow.net/q/130255/6094)

["Shortest closed curve to inspect a sphere"](https://mathoverflow.net/q/69099/6094)

Comment: Happy New Year!

Comment: Likewise.  I get 5 for the icosahedron by following edges.  Gerhard "And Happy Valentine's Day Too" Paseman, 2015.12.31.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: Ah, yes, I see the $5$-edge path. Thanks!

Comment: The problem for the curved surface (inspecting the sphere)  does not seem to the limiting case of the polyhedral version. Do you have a link in mind ?

Comment: @ARi: I wonder if, say, the optimal path on a geodesic dome might approach the path [*on* a sphere](http://mathoverflow.net/q/130255/6094) (with appropriate radius of visibility). The path to inspect a sphere from the space exterior to the sphere is rather different.

Comment: Someone has taken out a patent on a "polyhedron inspection apparatus", https://www.google.com/patents/US6892593 (but don't bother going there, it has nothing to do with the question).